# How to fix SUM when return duplicate row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

I'm trying to make a request which results some SUM and COUNT. But some SUM rows are false because of duplicate inner join rows. I tried so many ideas but no one worked at the moment.

With INNER JOIN, when i have multiple rows on invoiceRow or invoicePayment, sum of invoice rows are false (ex : if I have 4 rows on invoiceRow, I will have Sum(invoice) multiplied by 4).

**INVOICE**

```
id
customer
repertory
subTotal
totalPaid
```

**CUSTOMER**

```
id
name
```

**INVOICEROW**

```
id
invoice
type
```

**INVOICEPAYMENT**

```
id
invoice
method
amount
```

If somebody can help me, thanks by advance.

I have tried some `SUM(DISTINCT)` but it doesn't really work as i want to.

**sql results with inner join**

```
SELECT DATE(i.endDate), 
c.currency,
ir.type,
ip.method, 
AVG(i.totalPaid), 
COUNT(DISTINCT i.repertory), 
COUNT(DISTINCT i.id), 
SUM(i.subTotal), 
SUM(i.totalPaid)
from invoice i 
INNER JOIN invoiceRow ir ON ir.invoice=i.id 
INNER JOIN invoicePayment ip ON ir.invoice=ip.invoice 
INNER JOIN customer c ON c.id=i.customer
where i.customer=21 and i.totalPaid is not null and ip.method IN (3)
GROUP BY DATE(i.endDate);
```

**results without inner join**

```
SELECT DATE(i.endDate),
c.currency, 
AVG(i.totalPaid), 
COUNT(DISTINCT i.repertory), 
COUNT(DISTINCT i.id), 
SUM(i.subTotal), 
SUM(i.totalPaid)
from invoice i 
INNER JOIN invoiceRow ir ON ir.invoice=i.id 
INNER JOIN invoicePayment ip ON ir.invoice=ip.invoice 
INNER JOIN customer c ON c.id=i.customer
where i.customer=21 and i.totalPaid is not null
GROUP BY DATE(i.endDate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customer should be parent, so it can exists int the query with a join when you use Sum(). InvoiceRow and InvoicePayment however, don't seem to have any contribution to the result other than an existence check:

```
SELECT DATE(i.endDate),
c.currency, 
AVG(i.totalPaid), 
COUNT(i.repertory), 
COUNT(i.id), 
SUM(i.subTotal), 
SUM(i.totalPaid)
from invoice i 
INNER JOIN customer c ON c.id=i.customer
where i.customer=21 and i.totalPaid is not null AND
    exists (select * from invoiceRow ir 
        INNER JOIN invoicePayment ip ON ir.invoice=ip.invoice
        where ir.invoice=i.id)
GROUP BY DATE(i.endDate), c.Currency;
```

EDIT: As you said there were fields from other tables, here is how you should handle it:

```
SELECT DATE(i.endDate),
    c.currency, 
    AVG(i.totalPaid), 
    COUNT(i.repertory), 
    COUNT(i.id), 
    SUM(i.subTotal), 
    SUM(i.totalPaid),
    irp.Type, irp.Method
    from invoice i 
    INNER JOIN customer c ON c.id=i.customer
    inner join (select distinct i.id, ir.Type, ip.Method 
    from invoice inv
    inner join invoiceRow ir 
    INNER JOIN invoicePayment ip ON ir.invoice=ip.invoice
    where ir.invoice=inv.id)irp on irp.invoice = i.id
    where i.customer=21 and i.totalPaid is not null
    GROUP BY DATE(i.endDate), c.Currency, irp.Type, irp.Method;
```

In general it looks weird to have type and method on InvoiceRow and InvoicePayment, I would expect them to be on header.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i need on my select ir.type and ip.method in order to display them on a DTT (ajax), that's why i used join. My bad, I've forgotten to write it.

Comment: @NicolasLaurent, yes you should have included them. Actually while asking a question you should also include some sample data and expected output. Anyways, I will edit taking that into account.

Comment: That's right, but I think have an idea with your answer. I thank you very much for your help.